# how to get the value of id if its id is an integer value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the id of `<p>`.T have coded like this:

```
  var p = $(this).closest('li').find('p[id^=name]').text();
```

It returns only the text value,not the number.

My code is like this:

```
$.each(response.mname, function (i, mname) {
    $('#feat').append(
        '<li>' + '<a>' +
        '<h4>' + '<p id=name' + i +'>' + mname.Name + '</p>' + '</h4>' +
        '<input type="button" value="infobutton" background-color="green" id="button' + i +'" >' + '</input>' +
        '</a>' + '</li>');
});
    $("input[id^=button]").click(function () {
        var p = $(this).closest('li').find('p[id^=name]').text();
        alert(p);
    });
```

Comment: If I am getting you right, then your id is like this: `name1` `name2` etc. and you want those `1`s and `2`s instead of the contents of the `p` itself??

Comment: here i mean suppose mname.Name contains values like 24 ,25 then is it possible to get this values by using var p = $(this).closest('li').find('p[id^=name]').text();
        alert(p); because in alert i m getting blank value not also null.

Comment: @user3248668 check with below answer in order to get id use `.attr('id')`

Comment: @user3248668: In that case your code works perfectly fine. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/54URK/

Comment: thanks but in $("input[id^=button]").click(function () {//code}); here button is not any id right..?then id^=button what does button mean in this..?

Comment: It means an id which starts with "button". `^` to start with and `$` to end with. Please read up the jQuery docs on selectors.

Comment: in ur jsfiddle button1 and button2 are ids but there is no any button with id.please correct me if i m wrong.

Comment: @user3248668: Yes. So we bind the click handler to all buttons having an id which starts with "button" so that includes "button1" and "button2" both. That is what the `[id^=button]` selector does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
'<p id="name' + i +'">'
```

Also change if you want id

```
var p = $(this).closest('li').find('p[id^=name]').attr('id').replace(/name/, '');
```

It will return only integer 1,2 from names like name1,name2 etc..

Comment: sorry i have not tried this code but my problem is in id=name i m appending value from server which contains integer value such that id =name will contain value 24 .then var p = $(this).closest('li').find('p[id^=name]').text();alert(p) should give me value 24.hope u understood my problem if the solution is same for my problem then let me know.